# Getting data between time periods using Foursquare API

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, foursquare, epoch

I am building an app which will give your checkins on foursquare between time period chosen by the user. I researched the foursquare API but it ends up giving me afterTimestamp and beforeTimestamp.

> afterTimestamp :  sample value - 1279044824    : Retrieve the first results to follow these
>   seconds since epoch. This should be useful for paging forward in time,
>   or when polling for changes. To avoid missing results when polling, we
>   recommend subtracting several seconds from the last poll time and then
>   de-duplicating.
>
> beforeTimestamp : sample value - 1279044824   : Retrieve the first results prior to these
>   seconds since epoch. Useful for paging backward in time.

Now I looked up epoch to be 1/1/1970 everywhere inlcuidng linux but how do I get checkins , say between 10/10/2012 and 10/12/2012 . Would it be x second after epoch till 10/10/2012 ? This sounds outrageously complex and convoluted and impractical .

Any help ?

Comment: What you have suggested sounds right, have you tried to implement this? Also this isn't impractical, but a standard because around the world there are many different ways to write the same date (eg. in america its month/day/year, and europe it can be year/month/day). By using seconds your given a standard with out conversion. It is even more convoluted to write a script to handle any date format given to it. In python there are good libraries to handle this conversion for you as well. import datetime; timediff=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1); timediff.total_seconds()

Comment: Thanks I found a library to convert the epoch time to date/year.